# how to watch a folder of Azure Storage Explorer BLOB

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-dashboard

we have some blob containers in Azure Storage,
I would like to have a Dashboard with links to some specific folders e.g. to see at one glance the latest files in a specific folder of the Blob Container.

At the moment it is only possible with some clicks, navigation down and sorting into the folder.

I already tried to create a Metrics chart on the Dashboard, but it gives me only BLOB count and stats for the whole BLOB not for granular folders.

Any ideas how to whatch specific folders immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thing is, folders don't exists in Azure Storage Blobs. There are only containers and blobs inside containers. Blobs define *virtual* folders. Tools like the Azure Portal or Azure Storage Explorer use the `/` seperator in the blob url as a way to present a virtual folder structure.

So the answer is that it is impossible since there are no physical folders, as stated in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction#blob-storage-resources) as well:

> Blob storage offers three types of resources:
>
> - The storage account.
> - A container in the storage account
> - A blob in a container