# How to get Direct Link to Container(Folder) in Azure Storage Explorer for Azure Blob Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-explorer

I would like to get the direct link to a container(Folder) inside my blob storage account in Azure Storage Explorer. When I click on get direct link to blob container, it provides link only to the root level of the blob which looks something like this:

```
storageexplorer://v=1&accountid=[account id]&subscriptionid=[subscription id]&resourcetype=Azure.BlobContainer&resourcename=myblobnameV1
```

How do I add the subsequent folder paths to this direct link? So I would like something like the following:

```
storageexplorer://v=1&accountid=[account id]&subscriptionid=[subscription id]&resourcetype=Azure.BlobContainer&resourcename=myblobnameV1/CountryName/StoreName/
```

Currently the above gives resource not found error. I've looked around in the official documentation but couldn't find any way to do this. Can anyone help me find the solution or hack to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thing is, folders don't exists in Azure Storage Blobs. There are only containers and blobs inside containers. Blobs define virtual folders. Tools like the Azure Portal or Azure Storage Explorer use the `/` seperator in the blob url as a way to present a virtual folder structure.

So the answer is that it is impossible since there are no physical folders, as stated in the docs as well:

---

```
Blob storage offers three types of resources:

 - The storage account.
 - A container in the storage account
 - A blob in a container
```

Source : [how to watch a folder of Azure Storage Explorer BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58431456/how-to-watch-a-folder-of-azure-storage-explorer-blob)

Comment: Even though folders do not exist in blobstores and are modelled by having separators in blob names, the MS storage explorer allows to navigate the blobs using these virtual folders and a direct link with a `storageexplorer://` scheme could support direct navigation into folders, yet it does not :(